# How would I loop my code to have 4 histograms instead of 1?

Tags: r

```
N <- 10000 ; maxbound = 20 

one_side_normal <- function(N) {
  f <- numeric(N);
  for (i in 1:N) {
    X = rexp(1,rate=1);
    uniform = runif(1);
    while (uniform>exp((-X^2)+X) ){
      X = rexp(1,rate=1);
      uniform=runif(1);
    }
    f[i] <- X
  }
  return(f)
}
```

The above code samples from a one sided normal distribution(sample =10000) using the acceptance-rejection method. How would I loop this code to run 4 separate times for samples of 10,100,1000 & 10000?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the `N` values and apply the function.  As there is only a single argument, we don't need any lambda function.  It will return a `list`

```
lst1 <- lapply(c(10, 100, 1000, 10000), one_side_normal)
```

---

Another option is the classic `for` loop.  To store the output, we can create a `NULL` `list` of fixed length i.e length of the vector of 'N' values.  Then, loop over the sequence of 'N', apply the function and assign (`<-`) the output to the corresponding `list` element with that index

```
nvec <- c(10, 100, 1000, 10000)
lst1 <- vector('list', length(nvec))
for(i in seq_along(nvec)) lst1[[i]] <- one_side_normal(nvec[[i]])
```